# Can you have two Google Cloud Projects that talk to the same Cloud SQL Database?

Tags: mysql, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have just created a Project in Google Cloud, and attached a Cloud SQL Database instance to that project. I was able to deploy a Django app that is connected to that DB just fine.

However, I would like to create a separate Django app/Project that is attached to the same Cloud SQL Database that my first Django app is attached to.

*Is this possible?*

One Django app is responsible for web scraping and supplying constant data to the database while my second Django app (the one I have already deployed) analyzes and returns json on that data. It would be advantageous to separate the two apps because if I ever needed to revise my web scraping algorithm, the whole app would not be down.

Comment: How do you access to your database? Via IP? via Cloud SQL proxy? Via embedded connexion definition (in App Engin, Cloud Run or Cloud Function)?

Comment: To connect to the DB locally, I am currently using the proxy. Is there a way I can deploy a separate Django app, with a separate domain, that is connected to the same Cloud SQL instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudsql proxy for both apps. Also as long as you authorize both of your applications with [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) that have access to the cloudsql it should be fine.

Comment: It seems that cloudsql proxy is used to connect to the Cloud SQL DB from your local machine. I would like to deploy a separate django app, with a separate domain, that can connect to the same DB instance.

Comment: Which deployment mechanism that you're using? If you are using kubernetes you can create a deployment + service for cloudsql proxy and both of your apps can refer to that service.

Comment: I am running Django on the App Engine standard environment. It seems that in this mechanism each project (domain) is attached to one SQL instance.

Comment: Is there any documentation mentioned that? I just checked out that as long as your apps has the right to connect to the cloudsql (even though it's on different project). Have you see this one? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#python I believe for each of instance is named after <project-id>:<region>:<instance-name>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use database that you want, in your current project or in an external one. If you use Cloud SQL proxy, the service account of your app

- Either Default AppENgine service account if on App Engine
- Or Compute Engine default service account

  - except is you have defined a specific service account on your component (Cloud Run, Compute engine)
  - *I recommend strongly to use a specific service account on the component if it's possible (not possible with App Engine)*

The role to grant on the service account is the following: `roles/cloudsql.client`

***However***, I recommend you to smartly think to your design. The current trend is to lock 1 database to 1 service (or microservice).

Think about the schema update: a synchronous update will be required between to 2 services when  you update the schema or one, or the other app will fail.

Same thing in case of rollback, both apps need to be rollbacked.

If there is 2 teams, one on each app, their release planning must be sync, and you will lost in velocity and agility.

Maybe, it fits your requirement, or you can duplicate the data, inside the database (other schema). As you wish.

Comment: Guillaume, I have a Django app running on App Engine standard environment that is tied to a Cloud SQL DB. This app is an API that queries data from the database and returns it in JSON. I would like to deploy a separate Django app, on a separate domain that continuously web-scrapes data and inputs it into the same Cloud SQL instance. Is this possible?

Comment: Of course, it's possible. I just warned you about the difficulties of futur updates!

Comment: Problem is, Cloud SQL is insanely expensive, so have having an instance for each app/environment is costly

Comment: Agree, I constantly ask Google for a serverless pay-as-you-use relational database....